# AVRoutePickerView Won't Change Color when Airplay is Active

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a AVRoutePickerView in a ViewController that I can't get to change color when it's using Airplay.

```
AVRoutePickerView *routePickerView = [AVRoutePickerView new];
routePickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
routePickerView.activeTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
routePickerView.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

//I put it in a StackView, incidentally
    [self.bottomButtonStack insertArrangedSubview:routePickerView atIndex: 3]; 
    [routePickerView.layer setFrame:CGRectMake(80,80,80,80)];
    [routePickerView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:52].active = true;
    [routePickerView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:52].active = true;
```

This works fine, but the button always stays the tintColor even when an AirPlay source is being used from the picker.

**How do I get the button to change to the activeTintColor when Airplay is active?**

I thought it was automatically supposed to use the activeTintColor when Airplay was active. If no colors are set, the color of the button is always blue no matter what.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven’t seen this behavior before. Indeed when I select a route the active tint color is applied for me. Can you reproduce in a sample project?

Answer (score 10):

I first noticed this problem after upgrading to iOS 12.3.  I have since discovered that creating an instance of AVRouteDetector causes AVRoutePickerView to correctly apply the activeTintColor.  Just create the detector and retain in a member variable:

```
   self.myDetector = AVRouteDetector()

   // create route picker view as usual
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe this isn't stated anywhere in the docs! Spent hours trying to figure out what I did wrong... Thanks!!! So poorly documented, its outrageous

Answer (score -1):

you need set `routePickerButtonStyle`

```
let routePickerView = AVRoutePickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100))
    routePickerView.routePickerButtonStyle = .custom
    routePickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    routePickerView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(routePickerView)
```

Comment: Your solution is specific to tvOS as the button style is not supported on iOS which the OP was asking about.